# Multi checkbox with grouping in dropdown using primefaces JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I need to have a dropdown list which has to be grouped and also should be able to multi select using checkbox using primefaces. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no PrimeFaces component ready to use in your case. The cloesest ones are [*SelectOneMenu*](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) (dropdown list with grouping, but single selection without checkbox) and [*SelectCheckboxMenu*](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml) (dropdown list with multi selection and checkbox, but without grouping).

I do not see any chance in customizing *SelectOneMenu* to suit your needs. But extending [*SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer*](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectcheckboxmenu/SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.java) to support [*SelectItemGroup*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItemGroup.html) **may be an option** for *SelectCheckboxMenu*.

The idea behind is to traverse the full hierarchy, render all *SelectItemGroups* as non selectable options and all leaf [*SelectItems*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) as normal options. The concrete implementation is up to you.

If your hierarchy is flat **another simple approach** can be, to mimic groups by disabled *SelectItems* with *SelectCheckboxMenu*. Visually not the best result but it should fulfill your needs. An example for a `<f:selectItems />` *value* can be

```
List<SelectItem> options = Arrays.asList(
  new SelectItem("group1", "group1", "group1", true), 
  new SelectItem("option1", "option1", "option1", false),
  new SelectItem("option2", "option2", "option2", false),
  new SelectItem("group2", "group2", "group2", true),
  new SelectItem("option3", "option3", "option3", false),
  new SelectItem("option4", "option4", "option4", false)
);
```

Comment: I have used dialog to display 2 groups separately with the checkbox. In that way I was able to meet my requirement